# Virtual Machine, HD dynamically grow not growing

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm using a Windows 7 Ultimate x64 to install some applications on VIRTUALBOX 5.1.8, and set as HD Dinamically Grow, however its not growing. It does not pass from 25GB (like the initial disk space), even downloading files to force it to grow (Note: my host has free 27.5 GB and my virtual HD, only 1,6 MB). Please keep in mind that I'm just a student and I'm trying my best to learn and solve my problems by myself.

Thank you for your attention.

[First screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1wDd.png)
[Second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nfqN.png)

Comment: it only grows if needs to. initial size is 25GB, what's the maximum size? how did you *force* it to grow?

Comment: Submit some additional information, size of system partition for the vm, for starters

Comment: David , I'm not sure where those informations are. When I created I set as VDI and dynamically grow, HD size at 25GB, without max or min space. I forced download things. Ramhound where this information are supposed to be? I'll add some pics to show you all the screens of the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't what the dynamically growing disk means.

What it does mean is the originally created disk 'file' is a small size when the machine is made, and that file expands as it's needed (up until the size you set when making the machine).

I'm unsure if you're able to expand a existing VMs drive once it has data on it.

Comment: Waitwaitwait, so, that step, when it said "file size" is the Max size the HD can reach? Is that it? It's not like: "This is the inital size, but you can grow whenever you want"??

Comment: @ThiagoHenrique yup exactly, however you might be able to expand it, I'm unsure how.

Comment: Geez, thanks for the help. I was about a week with this problem.